# Vista's Unique Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, windows

I've always been a big fan of keyboard shortcuts, and one of my favorites was for times when I'd lost mouse control due to a deal battery and I needed to respond to something or other flashing in the system tray (usually an email or IM client that I've banished to that corner.)

```
Windows Key, Tab, Tab
```

However in Vista, Tab moves you through the different sections of the start menu, leaving me with no way to get to my precious messages. Does anyone know of a replacement shortcut? And what other Vista-only keyboard shortcuts have you found that might even make life better than it was in XP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I appreciate gabrieleponti and David's responses, however I actually did a little more hunting on my own and discovered a super-secret shortcut that doesn't seem to be listed in the common documentation.

```
Windows Key + B
```

Will actually take you right to the system tray!

Comment: Pretty neat! And it isn't listed on the Microsoft page. Good find! +1

Answer (score 7):

And, of course, a link to the Microsoft page listing [all shortcuts](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-US/help/2503b91d-d780-4c80-8f08-2f48878dc5661033.mspx) should be handy as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're specifically asking for Vista-only keyboard shortcuts, here is a list:

- Win + g: cycles the Gadgets selections.
- Win + Spacebar: brings Gadgets to the front
- Win + x: cycles though the Mobility Center.
- Win + TAB: activates Flip 3-D.
- Win + u: activates the Ease of Use Center.
- Win + t: cycles through Taskbar Programs
- Alt + TAB variant: press Win+1 or +2 and so on. This cycles the open programs on the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Try Windows + D, then Tab as you like.

Comment: You probably meant Windows + B, like Jax mentions.

Answer (score 0):

`Windows Key, Left, Right`

Will show the [notorious](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/11/21.html) Vista shutdown menu.